# Why can't I access an API with Python, but I can do it with my browser?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I want to access an API with Python but it's not working. I get this JSON file:

```
{"status": 403, "message": "Forbidden"}
```

My code:

```
result = requests.get(f"https://api.henrikdev.xyz/valorant/v2/match/06a29aa4-7862-4d6b-85f7-1fda200386f1").json()
with open("result.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(result, f)
```

But when I access the API on my browser it works: https://api.henrikdev.xyz/valorant/v2/match/06a29aa4-7862-4d6b-85f7-1fda200386f1

Comment: The browser sends headers with the request. Start here - https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working smoothly. You have to just inject user-agent as header

```
import requests
import json
headers={'User-Agent':'mozilla/5.0'}
result = requests.get(f"https://api.henrikdev.xyz/valorant/v2/match/06a29aa4-7862-4d6b-85f7-1fda200386f1",headers=headers).json()
jdata =  json.dumps(result,indent=4)
with open("result.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(jdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your same example but I am getting an error
Can you tell me what happens?

```
  "message": "The application has encountered an error",
            "type": "NullPointerError"
```

import requests
import json
import urllib.parse

```
query = "SELECT min({cart_pai.pk}) FROM {cart as carrinho JOIN cart AS cart_pai ON {carrinho.parent} = {cart_pai.pk}}"
safe_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)

headers = {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': 'Bearer 4DmQkomKs0z845705JIlfW-hhNg'}

result = requests.get(f"https://api.cokecxf-commercec1-p1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/clarowebservices/v2/claro/flexiblesearch/export/search/getAsCsv?"+safe_string,
                      headers=headers).json()
jdata = json.dumps(result, indent=4)
with open("result.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(jdata)
print(jdata)
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35856914)